# No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'setShowsUserLocation:'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, mapkit

I have a viewController which contains UItableView, Map view, and segment control as in the image below:

![enter image description here][1]

TestViewController.h

```
@interface TestViewController UIViewController:<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {CLLocationManager * locationManager;}
```

TestViewController.m

```
 MyMap.delegate=self;
// Ensure that you can view your own location in the map view.
[MyMap setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

the UItableView is working fine but it show an error when I write "[MyMap setShowsUserLocation:YES];"

Here is the error message: 
 No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'setShowsUserLocation:'

thanks in advance

Comment: ...and where's the image ?

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't put it there since I am a new user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyMap` is declared as `UITableView` in `@interface`. Change it to `MKMapView`.

Answer (score 1):

Examine your error more carefully. According to that, `MyMap` class is a sub class of `UITableView` and not `MKMapView` as it should be.

So, in `MyMap.h` file, change :

```
@interface MyMap : UITableView
```

to

```
@interface MyMap : MKMapView
```

What your error is telling you is that in the class `UITableView`, there is no method named `setShowsUserLocation`, and that is right. Hence, the change of parent class to `MKMapView`.

---

In the case that your `outlet` is incorrectly set, fix it by removing the desired `outlet` from the `UITableView` and set it to the required `MKMapView` object.

Comment: You're wrong MyMap is not a class, but an object. I agree that it's bad code style. But still.

Comment: He's created an object of that class in his code. He has to modify the class, **because objects are created from a class**. Therefore, only if he modifies the class MyMap to be a subclass of `MKMapView`, will the objects follow.

Comment: Then the outlet is set incorrectly to an `UITableView` rather than a `MKMapView`.

Comment: yeah I did set it to UItableView incorrectly... now it is working fine

Comment: So, my answer did fix your question. You've been very unfair with marking mine as incorrect :'(